# Finding the average height and average velocity of a ball dropped from height of $400$ ft

Tags: calculus, integration

> Rosanne drops a ball from a height of 400 ft. Find the ball's
>   average height and its average velocity between the time it is
>   dropped and the time it strikes the ground.

My trial...

So, I tried to use average value theorem for integrals. I took acceleration as positive $32$ ft m/s$^2$ (as velocity increases). By integrating it, I found velocity as $v=32t + C$ (with $C=0$). I integrated it one more time and got the distance $16 t^2 = 400$. And now $t = 5$ sec. After that, I tried to use average value of the function theorem. Somehow got the wrong answer. For finding H average and I did the following. (1/5)*(integral(from 0 to 5) Htdt. For this integral I found the answer 400/3 while answer given is 800/3

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the "trial" was added after the almost complete solution has been posted for 10+ minutes.

Comment: @user302797 Note that at first the aker posted his work by comments now deleted and it was done very quickly. Please reviseyour evaluation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $v_0=0$, we have that

- $h(t)=400-\frac12gt^2 \implies t_{max}=\sqrt{\frac{800}{g}}=20\sqrt{\frac{2}{g}}$ time to strike the ground
- $v(t)=gt \implies v_{max}=20\sqrt{2g} \implies \bar v=\frac{v_0+v_{max}}{2}$

and

$$\bar h = \frac{\int_0^{t_{max}}h(t) dt}{t_{max}}$$

Comment: Does this always hold $\bar v=\frac{v_0+v_{max}}{2}$? I mean it is good in this case but it should be total displacement/ total time.

Comment: @SameerBaheti It holds because $v$ is linear in that case.

Comment: Oh yes! If acceleration is constant and path is straight line one can prove this by $v^2-u^2=2as$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H=400\text{ft}$.
$$h(t)=H-\frac12gt^2$$ 
Average height = particular height $\times$ time during which it was on that height/ total time.
$$\frac12gT^2=H\implies T=\sqrt{\frac{2H}g}$$
Or mathematically
$$<h>=\frac{\int_0^Th(t)dt}{\int_0^Tdt}$$
$$<h>=\frac{\int_0^T(H-\frac12gt^2)dt}T=H-\frac{\frac16g\big[t^3\big]_0^T}T=H-\frac{H}3=\frac{2H}3=\frac{800}3\text{ft}$$
$v(t)=gt.$
So, similarly $$<v>=\frac1T\int_0^Tgtdt=\frac HT=\sqrt{\frac{Hg}2}$$